# Build unity 7 from source for ubuntu 15.04

Tags: unity, compiz, 15.04, compiling

I followed the instructions at [build unity from source](https://unity.ubuntu.com/getinvolved/development/unity)

on Ubuntu desktop 15.04 but it didn't work when I do `make install` it exits with error **cannot create /pam.d** it requires a privileged user.
If I do `sudo make install` it works fine but after that I cannot login to my Ubuntu desktop anymore with the same user and to fix this I have to delete ~./compiz-1 to be able to login again.
Please could somebody provide me with the instructions to build and install unity 7 from source and how can I test it after I install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some bugs in the link above:

1. I need to modify the CMakeLists.txt file in data directory by commenting the single line in it, because this line tries to install **unity** file inside **/pam.d** directory where normal users cannot do this, so I created the folder manually and copied the file then changed permissions.
2. I had to manually create the folder **~/staging/lib/python2.7/site-packages**.
3. I need to pay attention to the last **N** in the command `cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCOMPIZ_PLUGIN_INSTALL_TYPE=local -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$HOME/staging/ -DGSETTINGS_LOCALINSTALL=ON` because you might copy without it.